# connect-redis client.unref is not a function

Tags: node.js, redis, express-session, redisclient

I am setting up redis with express-session in node.

I am getting this error:

```
if (options.unref) this.client.unref();
this.client.unref is not a function
```

this error points to redis-connect's library in my node_modules.

here's the basic code I have in node:

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var redis = require('redis');
var redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
```

then,

```
var client = redis.createClient();
var sessionStore = new redisStore(client);

app.use(session({
  store: sessionStore,
  secret: 'a stringy string thing',
}))
```

how do I address the error?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of creating the Redis store instance:

```
var sessionStore = new redisStore({ client : client });
```

In other words, `redisStore` requires an options object to be passed as argument, and not the Redis client instance directly.